# How do I catch error in tbl in dplyr while fetching data from the database?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

Sometimes I run into an issue where the database query generates error. One example is:

`nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3069: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index`

I know why the error occurs but I can't seem to catch the error to try something else when something like this happens.

```
result <- tryCatch(
      data <- tbl(conn, query),
      
      error = function(e){
        
        print("Error encountered: ", e)
        print("Attempting to run by sorting the columns")
        
        
        new_query <- create_query_with_column_names(query)
        
        print("Attempting to fetch the data with the new query")
        data <- tbl(conn, new_query)
        
        end_time <- Sys.time()
        
        
        show_query_runtime(total_time=end_time-start_time, caller="fetch data without lazy loading.")
        
      }
    )
```

But instead, the code runs without error, but when I run the result, I get the error again.

`> result`

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3069: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index 
Warning message:
In dbClearResult(res) : Result already cleared
```

The above code won't catch the error. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it just fails on the new query within the error part? You can try putting a `browser()` within the error part and run it line by line to see what happens.

Comment: @AdroMine, thank you for your response. The script doesn't fair on the new query within the error part. It errors out after reading `rs <- tbl(conn, query)` when `rs` is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/7742981) answer for detailed guidance on `tryCatch` in R.

The problem is most likely how you are returning values.

- If it executes correctly, the Try part returns the last statement in the section.
- If the Try does not execute correctly, then the error section will return the last statement in the section.

Right now, the last statement in your error section is `show_query_runtime(...)` but what it looks like you want is `tbl(conn, new_query)`.

Try the following, note the use of `return` to specify the value that should be returned:

```r
result <- tryCatch(
  # try section
  data <- tbl(conn, query),

  # error section
  error = function(e){
    print("Error encountered: ", e)
    print("Attempting to run by sorting the columns")
    new_query <- create_query_with_column_names(query)

    print("Attempting to fetch the data with the new query")
    data <- tbl(conn, new_query)
    
    end_time <- Sys.time()
    show_query_runtime(total_time=end_time-start_time, caller="fetch data without lazy loading.")

    return(data)
  }
)
```

In case it is part of the confusion, assigning `data <- tbl(conn, new_query)` within a function does not make the assignment in the calling environment. The variable `data` is not available once the `tryCatch` finishes. This is why we need to return the result out of the calling function.